# Как в GridView yii2 изменить view?

Tags: php, yii2

То есть сейчас выводится стандартная таблица yii, хочу поменять шаблон вывода на подобии itemView

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'itemView' => '_item',
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'published_at:date',
            'title',
            [
                'attribute'=>'category_id',
                'value'=>function ($model) {
                    return $model->category ? $model->category->title : null;
                },
                'filter'=>\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\common\models\ArticleCategory::find()->all(), 'id', 'title')
            ],
            [
                'class'=>\common\grid\EnumColumn::className(),
                'attribute'=>'status',
                'enum'=>[
                    Yii::t('backend', 'Not Published'),
                    Yii::t('backend', 'Published')
                ]
            ],
            //'published_at:datetime',
            //'created_at:datetime',
            // 'updated_at',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template'=>'{update} {delete}'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: А почему не используете ListView? Там именно так все и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Для редактирования отображения виджета, придется изменить сам виджет. Поэтому придется разобраться вообще как осуществляется работа виджета в yii. Для примера исходный gridView ты можешь посмотреть в vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid . Можешь посмотреть также готовые варианты [grid](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/grids/view/gridview.html).